# Check if username exist in asp.net using stored procedure and adding values to Registration.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've created a stored procedure in SQL Server to check if username exists in the database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCheckUsernameForAnswer]
     @username VARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count INT

    SELECT @count = COUNT(username) 
    FROM Users 
    WHERE [username] = @username 

    IF (@count = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 1 AS ReturnCode
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 AS Returncode
    END
END
```

Here is what I've done in Visual Studio `Registration.aspx.cs`.

I need to check if the username exists and if not to insert the required values into db to register a new user.

From the code below it keeps registering new users with the same username again and again.

Any idea what am I missing here?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Guid newGUID = Guid.NewGuid();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCheckUsernameForAnswer", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter parausername = new SqlParameter("@username", TextBoxUN.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parausername);

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["ReturnCode"]))
            {
                Label1.Text = "Username found";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "not found";
            }
        }

        conn.Close();

        SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        conn1.Open();

        string insertQuery = "insert into [Users] (user_id, first_name, last_name, email, username, password) values (@user_id, @first_name, @last_name, @email, @username, @password)";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn1);

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", newGUID.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", TextBoxFname.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", TextBoxLname.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUN.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPass.Text);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Write("Registration successful");

        conn1.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better use `cmd.ExecuteScalar` since the sp is returning either 1 or 0.

And it would be better to have the `insert into db part` in a separate method like `RegisterUser` method.

But the main thing is you need to call that method when it doesn't exist in db (in the `else` statement)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {         
        using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("spCheckUsernameForAnswer", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", TextBoxUN.Text));
                conn.Open();
                var returnCode = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if(returnCode == 1)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Username found";
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = "not found";
                    Register();
                }
            }
        }               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void RegisterUser()
{
    try 
    {
        var newGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
        using(var conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn1.Open();
            string insertQuery = "insert into [Users] (user_id, first_name, last_name, email, username, password) values (@user_id, @first_name, @last_name, @email, @username, @password)";
            using(var com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn1))
            {
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", newGUID.ToString());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", TextBoxFname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", TextBoxLname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUN.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPass.Text);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        Response.Write("Registration successful");
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        //log the exception;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, the edited code from you worked perfect! I've been trying to fix it for hours, I knew i messed up something, but I didn't know what and where. Highly appreciate your help!

Comment: @G.Hari glad I could help. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Try this not too sure why you used reader if i was you will handle everything in stored procedure

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {

    Guid newGUID = Guid.NewGuid();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCheckUsernameForAnswer", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter parausername = new SqlParameter("@username", TextBoxUN.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parausername);
    conn.Open();
    var userexsist = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (userexsist)
    {

        Label1.Text = "Username found";
        conn.close();
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "not found";


        string insertQuery = "insert into [Users] (user_id, first_name, last_name, email, username, password) values (@user_id, @first_name, @last_name, @email, @username, @password)";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", newGUID.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", TextBoxFname.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", TextBoxLname.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUN.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPass.Text);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("Registration successful");
        conn.Close();
    }        
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'M USING HELPER CLASS VS. SOON I WILL SENT ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

```
SqlHelper sho = new SqlHelper();
public bool alreadyexist()
        {
string[] str = { "@catname", "@proname" };       
string[] obj = { comboproductname.Text, comboitemname.Text };

SqlDataReader sdrr = sho.GetReaderByCmd("sp_item_alreadyex", str, obj);

if (sdrr.Read())
{
    sdrr.Close();
    sho.CloseConnection();
    return true;
}
else
{
    sdrr.Close();
    sho.CloseConnection();
    return false;
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
Create procedure [dbo].[sp_item_alreadyex]
    @catname nvarchar(50),
    @proname nvarchar(50)
as
begin
    select * 
    from Item 
    where Item_Name = @proname and Category = @catname
end
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Please don't reject or rollback edits to properly format your code. (And, in the future, please format your posts correctly yourself.) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it in stored procedure also. Find the solution:

```
USE [akhil_db]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_Insert_AddUser] 
(  
@fname varchar(200),
@lname varchar(200),
@userName varchar(200),
@userEmail varchar(200),  
@userPasword varchar(200),  
@userType varchar(200),
 @msg VARCHAR(100) OUT )  
AS  
BEGIN  
SET NOCOUNT ON;  
Declare @UserCount int;
SELECT @UserCount = COUNT(*) FROM user_master WHERE [user_name] = @userName or [user_email]=@userEmail;
IF(@UserCount > 0)
begin

 Set  @msg = 'User already exists';

end
ELSE
begin

Insert into user_master(
        user_fname,
        user_lname,
      [user_name]
      ,[user_email]
      ,[user_pasword]
     ,user_type
      )
       values(
        @fname,
        @lname,
       @userName
      ,@userEmail
      ,@userPasword
     ,@userType

      )
      SET @msg ='Registered Successfully'
END 
END 



Code behind c#



SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_Insert_AddUser", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", txtfname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", txtlname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", txtUserName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userEmail", txtUserEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userPasword", txtPass.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userType", ddlUserType.SelectedValue);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@msg", SqlDbType.Char, 500);
            cmd.Parameters["@msg"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string message = (string)cmd.Parameters["@msg"].Value;
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = message;

            con.Close();
```